# How to solve the NestJS error 'Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SurvivorService'?

Tags: typescript, service, module, nestjs

For no particular reason my NestJS not able to read SurvivorService.

Error:

` Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SurvivorService (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the SurvivorModule context.

Potential solutions:

- Is SurvivorModule a valid NestJS module?
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current SurvivorModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within SurvivorModule?
  @Module({
  imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  `

SurvivorService:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Survivor } from './survivor.entity';

@Injectable()
export class SurvivorService {
  constructor(
    @Inject()
    private readonly survivorRepository: Repository<Survivor>,
  ) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<Survivor[]> {
    return this.survivorRepository.find();
  }
}
```

SurvivorProvider:

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { Survivor } from './survivor.entity';

export const survivorProvider = [
  {
    provide: 'SURVIVOR_REPOSITORY',
    useFactory: (dataSource: DataSource) => dataSource.getRepository(Survivor),
    inject: ['DATA_SOURCE'],
  }
]
```

SurvivorModule:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DatabaseModule } from 'src/database.module';
import { survivorProvider } from './survivor.providers';
import { SurvivorService } from './survivor.service';

@Module({
  imports: [DatabaseModule],
  providers: [...survivorProvider, SurvivorService]
})

export class SurvivorModule {}
```

AppModule:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { SurvivorModule } from './survivor/survivor.module';

@Module({
  imports: [SurvivorModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: have you read the FAQ page: https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#cannot-resolve-dependency-error

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Inject('SURVIVOR_REPOSITORY')` to define the injection token, otherwise Nest is unaware of what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the import of the survivor.entity in the SurvivorModule class

```
imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Survivor])],
```